# Express server not responding to reqs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, ws

After sending a bunch of POST/GET reqs to the server my server stops responding and in the network tab of the console all the reqs are labeled as "pending".

I have logged timestamps during the responses but they go fast and they just don't run once the problem occurs.

Sever:

```
var ip = require('ip');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

var students = [];
var cons = [];

app.use(bodyParser.text({
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/add', function(req, res) {
  students.push(req.body);
  for (var i = 0; i < cons.length; i++) {
    cons[i].send(JSON.stringify(students));
  }
});
app.post('/del', function(req, res) {
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    if (students[i] == req.body) {
      students.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < cons.length; i++) {
    cons[i].send(JSON.stringify(students));
  }
});
app.get('/students', function(req, res) {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(students));
});
app.ws('/mes', function(ws, req) {
  cons.push(ws);
  ws.on('close', function(req) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cons.length; i++) {
      if (cons[i] == ws) {
        cons.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Sender:

```
function sendData() {
  if (okMes() == true) {
    console.log(student_i.value);
    fetch('/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: student_i.value
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
    student_i.value = '';
  }
}
```

Reciever:

```
function placeButton(data) {
  if (data.length == 0) {
    error_p.style.display = 'block';
    error_p.innerHTML = 'No New Students';
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(i) != null) {
      document.getElementById(i).remove();
    }
  }
  students = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    student = document.createElement('button');
    student.innerHTML = data[i];
    students_d.appendChild(student);
    students.push(student);
    student.setAttribute('id', students.length - 1);
    error_p.style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    students[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        if (students[i] == this) {
          students.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      // document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('id')).remove();
      fetch('/del', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: this.innerHTML
      });
      if (document.querySelectorAll('button') == []) {
        error_p.style.display = 'block';
        error_p.innerHTML = 'No New Students';
      }
    }
  }
}
// seting interval and fetching for '/students' and calling this func
// reciving ws.onmessage and calling this func
```

I have no idea why my reqs aren't being responded to and if anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Are you running the server with HTTPS? Try reaching one of the routes by copying the address and pasting it into the browser window. Perhaps you'll see that requests are being blocked because of an invalid SSL certificate and you need to manually allow the browser to bypass the security.

Comment: Im not running my server on HTTPS and when I go to those routes I get a response.

Comment: What's the console output on the server side?

Comment: I just log the url where its running right now. If you're wondering about the timings they all happened at the same time and when the problem occurred they stopped logging. EDIT: I made timestamps after each line and all of those happened when that func was called not all of the lines in unrelated funcs were logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fetch` API expects full `url`. Change your `fetch` call to:

```
// assuming you're running on localhost on port 3000
fetch('http://localhost:3000/del', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: this.innerHTML
});
```

Comment: I did this and it makes no difference about whether I add it or not.

Comment: what is your `cons[i].send`?

Comment: It is sending the data to all of the ws connections.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer while testing my code. It turned out I didn't `res.end()` when handling post reqs and I guess it the reqs might have timed out.